# Is boxing or explicit lifetimes the right solution when referencing a collection item in a loop?

Tags: rust, lifetime

In Rust (version 1.x) I want to use elements of a collection inside a loop such as the example 
below (which recors the characters it has seen and does something when it spots a repeated char) where the collection is defined inside the function and only used by the loop.

```
    fn do_something(word:&str) -> u32 {
            let mut seen_chars = HashMap::new();
            let mut answer : u32 = 0;
            for (i,c) in word.chars().enumerate() {
            let char_str = Box::new(c.to_string());
            match seen_chars.get(&char_str) {
                    Some(&index) => {
                    answer = answer + index;
                    },
                    None => {seen_chars.insert(char_str,i);}
            }; 

    }
    answer
    }
```

In order to store references to c in my hashmap (which I have declared outside the loop) I need to box c 
 and allocate it on the heap. This feels inefficent and like I must be doing something wrong. 
 I wondered if using explicit lifetimes would be a better way to do things, below is my best attempt but I can't get it to compile.

```
    fn do_something<'a>(word:&str) -> u32 {
            let mut seen_chars = : &'a HashMap<&str,usize> = &HashMap::new();
            let mut answer : u32 = 0;
            for (i,c) in word.chars().enumerate() {
            let char_str =  &'a str = &c.to_string();
            match seen_chars.get(&char_str) {
                    Some(&index) => {
                    answer = answer + index;
                    },
                    None => {seen_chars.insert(char_str,i);}
            }; 

    }
    answer
    }
```

When I try compiling I get "error: borrowed value does not live long enough" with an indication that "&HashMap::new()" is the problem.
 Can I use lifetime specification to solve this issue or am doing things the wrong way here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think either of your approaches is the best solution. You can just use the char itself as a key for your HashMap, no need to convert it to a String:

```
fn do_something(word:&str) -> usize {
    let mut seen_chars = HashMap::new();
    let mut answer : usize = 0;
    for (i,c) in word.chars().enumerate() {
        match seen_chars.get(&c) {
            Some(&index) => {
                answer = answer + index;
            },
            None => {seen_chars.insert(c,i);}
        };
    }
    answer
}
```

(I also had to change the type of `answer` to get this to compile, since `enumerate` gives you `usize`s . Alternatively, you could cast `i` to `u32` where necessary)

If, for some reason, you wanted to have string keys instead of `char`, you would have to use owned strings (i.e. `String`) instead of string slices (`&str`). You would end up with something like this:

```
fn do_something(word:&str) -> usize {
    let mut seen_chars : HashMap<String,usize> = HashMap::new();
    let mut answer : usize = 0;
    for (i,c) in word.chars().enumerate() {
        let char_str = c.to_string();
        match seen_chars.get(&char_str) {
            Some(&index) => {
                answer = answer + index;
            },
            None => {seen_chars.insert(char_str,i);}
        };
    }
    answer
}
```

But I strongly suspect that the first options is what you actually want.

Comment: Thank you. I see now I was so concentrated on trying to solve the bad borrow compile error that I didn't step back and look at if I 
 even needed the string conversion in the first place. In the case where you did actually need to create a new reference to add to a collection
 (For example some struct based on the character) would explicit lifetimes be the way to go?

Comment: No, explicit lifetimes probably wouldn't help you. The problem is that you can't put a reference to a value in a collection if the collection outlives the value that the reference points to, because the reference would become invalid. Explicit lifetime annotations never extend the lifetime of a value.